difference in UI between vscode flutter run and flutter run --release
When I run my Flutter project from VS Code, it works fine in both normal and debug modes. However, when I build the APK using flutter build apk, the text in my TextButton doesn't appear. I'm not sure why this is happening.
https://github.com/Ahmednahrawy/my_hand/tree/develop/lib
i tried deleting project and clone a copy again and also tried modifing alot of widget.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
